# Qt WiFi network scan

Tags: c++, qt

For some application I need to scan WiFi searching for available network (SSID). On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I don't have any issue with the fallowing code. It return all available SSID as expected but when running on Raspbian stretch (Rasberry PI 3 b) the fallowing code is returning the interface wlan0 and eth0 and not the SSID. Does someone have any clue why? or can tell me what I miss? On the other hand, is it better not to use Qt network lib and use a `QProcess` and parse what `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` is returning?

.cpp

```
void wificonfig::findavailableWifinetwork( void )
{
    QNetworkConfigurationManager ncm;
    netconflist = ncm.allConfigurations(QNetworkConfiguration::Discovered); //
    int i =0;
    awifilist.clear();

    for(auto &x : netconflist){
        if ((x.bearerType() == QNetworkConfiguration::BearerWLAN) ){
            if(x.name() == "")
                awifilist << "Unknown(Other Network)";
            else{

                ui->wificonnection_tw->setItem(i, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(x.name()));
                i++;
            }
            //qDebug() << x.type();
        }
    }
    ui->wificonnection_tw->setRowCount(i);
}
```

.h

```
#ifndef WIFICONFIG_H
#define WIFICONFIG_H

#include <QList>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QNetworkConfiguration>
#include <QNetworkConfigurationManager>
#include <QNetworkSession>

namespace Ui {
class wificonfig;
}

class wificonfig : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit wificonfig(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~wificonfig();
    int connection_count;
    QNetworkConfiguration netconf;
    QStringList awifilist;
    QList<QNetworkConfiguration>netconflist;

public slots:
    void findavailableWifinetwork( void );

private slots:
    void on_wifi_scan_butt_clicked();
private:
    Ui::wificonfig *ui;
    QTime *scan_timeout_timer;
    QNetworkSession *session;
};

#endif // WIFICONFIG_H
```

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is Raspbian is, but using QProcess is not the right solution to your problem. You could try looking in the Qt code for Raspbian and see why it finds eth0 as wireless network.

Comment: Yes, thank you I will try to do that. What is bothering me the most, is not the fact that eth0 is find as wireless network but the fact that on one platform it returned SSID name and informations about the network and on the other one it returned the hardware interface.